# How to export data from HTML table to excel using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, export-to-excel

I want to export data in my html table to an excel sheet using angularjs on abutton click. I tried a code, but in vain.i m getting the button click event triggered though but nothing else seems to happen

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover  table-striped" id="tableId">
<tr ng-repeat="mas in vm1 | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
                            <td>{{::mas.contractNumber}} </td>
                            <td>{{::mas.planNumber}} </td>
                            <td>{{::mas.businessErrorMsg }} </td>
                            <td>{{::mas.systemErrorMsg}} </td>

                        </tr>
 <button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="exportToExcel('#tableId')">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>Export to Excel
                        </button>
```

//controller code

```
app.controller("ErrorDetailController", [
    "$scope", "$location", "$routeParams", "messageService", "errorService", "repositoryService", , "sharedPageService",
    function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, messageService, errorService, repositoryService,sharedPageService, **Excel, $timeout**) {
$scope.exportToExcel = function (tableId) { // ex: '#my-table'

            debugger;
            var exportHref = Excel.tableToExcel(tableId, 'sheet name');
            $timeout(function () { location.href = exportHref; }, 100); // trigger download
        }
}
]);

app.factory('Excel', function ($window) {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
        template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
        base64 = function (s) { return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))); },
        format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) };
    return {
        tableToExcel: function (tableId, worksheetName) {
            var table = $(tableId),
                ctx = { worksheet: worksheetName, table: table.html() },
                href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
            return href;
        }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`ng-table-to-csv`](https://github.com/kollavarsham/ng-table-to-csv) module to export HTML tables into CSV files (that can be opened in Excel).

As given on the README of that repo, here is the usage:

> ### Getting Started / Usage
>
> Install module via bower (or download the files from the `dist` folder
>   in the repo):
>
> `shell bower install ng-table-to-csv --save`
>
> Add a reference to `dist/ng-table-to-csv.js` into your HTML pages.
>
> Add `ngTableToCsv` as a dependency to your module:
>
> `js angular.module('your_app', ['ngTableToCsv']);`
>
> Add `export-csv` attribute directive on the `table` to define a new
>   `csv` object on the scope with `generate()` and `link()` functions on
>   them.
>
> Options:
>    - Use the `separator` attribute to change the default comma separator into something else (like semicolon).
>    - Use the `export-csv-ignore` attribute to set the selector that will be used for prevent `tr`/`th`/`td` to be stringified.
>
> To create an `Export` button from an anchro tag, use the `generate()`
>   and `link()` functions mentioned above from `ng-click` and `ng-href`
>   attributes of an anchor tag.
>
> See below:
>
> `html
>         <a class="btn" title="Export Table" ng-click='csv.generate()' ng-href="{{ csv.link() }}"
>            download="myTable.csv">
>           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></i> &#160;Export
>         </a>
>         <table class="table table-bordered" export-csv="csv" separator=";">
>           <!-- table contents -->
>         </table>`

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
<body>{table}</body>
```

instead of :

`<body><table>{table}</table></body>` in template variable.